# Cross developing targeting both Java Swing and GWT

Tags: java, swing, gwt, cross-platform

Does anyone know of any tool that can facilitate/ease porting of an app to both Java Swing and GWT?

I've got a few "screens" that makes complete sense to have both in a desktop app and in a browser and I was wondering if there was some kind of common API that could be targeted that would facilitate creating these two different "views" (see my comment)?

Comment: Commenting on my own question: I actually do have extensive experience with "cross-platform development" having actually worked on a (commercial) software that generates hundreds (yes, hundreds) of different builds, targetting Brew/iPhone/Java phones from a unique codebase (think the now defunct Tira Wireless).  It worked by targetting a restricted API that was then automagically converted to C++/Obj-C code.  So basically what I'm after would be something similar (some simplified API) to develop both a Swing and a GWT app.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's entirely possible, but it would mean a different take on the server side of things.

If you do interface-based POJO development of the server-side components that the UI communicates with to do the work, you leave yourself the option of either an in-memory implementation or one that acts as a proxy to a remote component.  The Swing desktop UI might use the in-memory version of the server-side, while the GWT version talks to the distributed version.

If you use Spring, it's easy to inject the appropriate implementation for each UI.  Both only know about the interface and are oblivious to the implementation details.

I imagine a single code base that might be packaged in different ways.  The Swing desktop app would be packaged and delivered as a JAR file.  It wouldn't include the GWT or web tier controller classes.  The GWT code base would include web configuration and controllers, because controllers are really part of the web tier.

The service interface and everything behind it would remain the same for both.  The only difference would be that the Swing desktop configuration would inject the in-memory service layer implementations of the service interface.  The web configuration would inject the web-based implementations of the service interface.

Whether my attempt to read your mind for requirements is correct or not, this approach has value regardless of how you decide to implement the service and client tiers.

I'm a Spring fan, so I'd recommend the use of Spring.

Comment: @duffymo: oh that's very interesting... I didn't even think about that: but what about the UI implementations? Do these both needs to be separated/different implementations? Wouldn't it be possible to have a unique "codebase" for the UIs too? (actually I'm usually using HMVC/PAC UIs and I can easily "nest" screens into tabs etc., what I'd be after would be a few screens that would be easily portable between Swing and SWT)

Comment: @duffymo: I didn't precise it but basically, the desktop Swing app only makes sense when there's an internet connection and it's already constantly dialoging with our servers (not that it changes much).